# How to find the Position of String array item if I am showing value in dialog?

Tags: android

```
String [] strinArray={"A","B,"c","D"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        @Override

        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int item) {

          String value = stringArray[item];


       }
```

---

```
String [] strinArray={"A","B,"c","D"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        @Override

        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int item) {

          String value = stringArray[item];


       }
```

I want to get Position of item what I have selected ?

Comment: whats wrong? Do you have an error or incorrect value is selected ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494171/how-to-get-selected-item-of-a-singlechoice-alert-dialog)?

Comment: In the onclick method argument int item is the clicked item position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

set for loop and get position of string ;-

```
for (int i = 0; i < strinArray.length; i++) {
            if(strinArray[i].equals("A")){
               log.d("LOG", "Position of A is "+i);
                 }

        }
```

i is the position of your string;